# How to embed a property as a string argument in soapUI

Tags: xml, soapui

I have recently started using soapui to test web services and fairly new. I was wondering how to embed a property value as a string in the request. For example the request is like below

```
<org:Customer org1:Description="customer" org1:DisplayName="google" 
org1:Name="google"/>
```

Essentially I am looking to do this something like this,

```
<org:Customer org1:Description=${#Project#orgdesc}     
org1:DisplayName=${#Project#orgdisplayname}        
org1:Name=${#Project#orgdisplayname}/>
```

I have properties defined for all of the fields above at the project level for parameterizing my test. I am trying to embed these properties within the request. I tried following things but none of them work. Can someone please let me know what I am missing?

**Edit#1**

I think I am not doing the right thing below. Because in the original request above, Description, DisplayName and Name are the attributes of Customer and I sending the request by making them as child nodes below. It seems fundamentally incorrect. Then how do I embed value of the properties I defined within attributes of a tag?

**Attempt 1**

```
  <org:Customer> 
         <arg0>
            <org1:Description>${#Project#orgdesc}</org1:Description>
            <org1:DisplayName>${#Project#orgdisplayname}</org1:DisplayName>
            <org1:Name>${#Project#orgname}</org1:Name>
         </arg0>
  </org:Customer>
```

**Attempt 2**

```
 <org:Customer> 
             <org1:Description>
              <arg0>${#Project#orgdesc}</arg0>
             </org1:Description> 
             <org1:DisplayName>
               <arg0>${#Project#orgdisplayname}</arg0>
             </org1:DisplayName>
             <org1:Name>
               <arg0>${#Project#orgname}</arg0>
             </org1:Name>
     </org:Customer>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure that you simply have one too many '#' symbols.

I think the 'property expansion' syntax is what you need.  Like:

def postResp = context.expand('${PostObject#response}')

That is from a groovy script, but I think groovy is applied to the message templates before sending them, so:

${Project#orgname}

is probably what you need.

EDIT

In that case, try setting a 'lowest scope' variable from groovy and using that in your message.  Do something like:

def city= context.expand( '${#Project#city}' )

context.setProperty("city", city)

Then in the XML, put:

${city}

Here is a part of the XML request:

```
  <data:address>
     <data:street>${street}</data:street>
     <data:city>${city}</data:city>
     <data:state>${state}</data:state>
     <data:zipCode>${zip}</data:zipCode>
     <data:country>${country}</data:country>
  </data:address>
```

Comment: I think the syntax I have is correct for Project level properties because def name = context.expand('${#Project#orgname}') returns me the orgname I defined

Comment: thanks for the updated answer. I did add a groovy script like you suggested as a groovy step within the teststep. I then tried org1:Name=${org}, that obviously wouldn't work since quotes are required in the request. I also tried to insert the result of the groovy step like org1:Name=${getOrgName#result} but that didn't work either. Can you give me the xml request example that you are using?

Comment: Stuff like this is a mjaor reason for getting the pro version